# Shell script uses a temporary file. Any other way?

Tags: shell

I am trying to teach myself shell programming using the "Unix Programming Environment" book. I was trying to write a script to remove all the semaphores from the system. However I couldn't find a way that wouldn't use a temporary file. Here's the code that works but uses a temporary file. I'm sure there is a much easier solution. Please help.

```
# remsem: Remove all the semaphores

IFS='
'
set X`ipcs`
j=0
for i
do
        case $i in
        *semid*)        j=1;;
        *'Message Queues'*) break;;
        esac
        if [ $j = 1 ]
        then
                echo $i
        fi
done |
awk ' $1 != "key" { print $1 } ' > /tmp/remsem.$$
set `cat /tmp/remsem.$$`
for i
do
        `ipcrm -S $i`
done
rm /tmp/remsem.$$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), which lets you pass output from one program as command line parameters to another.

```
awk '...'| xargs ipcrm -S
```

or something similar should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only using the temporary file to assign to $1, $2, etc for the loop.  You can do:

```
for i in $( some command ); do ...; done
```

or

```
some command | while read i; do ...; done
```

(or use xargs as mentioned above)

Also, when using a tempfile, you typically want to have it removed automatically so that it doesn't hang around if the script is aborted early.  Something like:

```
FILE=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $FILE" 0
...
```